# 3D cryptic brain melter

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, three-dimensional

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #43: Variety Crossword Grids](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7062)</sup>

---

[image]

This is a three-dimensional cryptic crossword. The seven squares in the picture depict the layers of a 7x7x7 cube. The "away" clues run through these layers, starting from the top-left square in the picture.

**Across**
1. In Ireland, my teacher ignoring latest reminder (7)
9. Without emotion, I criticise broadcast (3-4)
15. Native American woman touring Ohio (7)
18. Small, partly destroyed island in South China Sea (6)
21. Breach home with unhinged baker (7)
22. Flexible pillar in flexible castle (7)
23. Legislation overturned by Republican leader, American individual with thick whiskers (6)
27. A French prison housing one native of Algeria, say (7)
28. Operation by one undercover member of the Police (5)
29. Males troubled by onset of epidemic, start of serious disease (7)
32. A lake near Asia's centre, located in region with no current (4,3)
33. Current session (7)

**Down**
1. Smallest fictional mouse quiet on recording (7)
3. Coin obtained by follower of pirate E. Teach (7)
5. Mostly avoiding fooling around, like some Latin poetry (7)
18. Fill, at last, vacancies a tech company picked? (7)
19. Winter clothing from Alaska's worn by woman (7)
20. Part of egg container holds, essentially, only extremities up (4,3)
24. Formula One driver Hathaway's returned (5)
25. Retired females adopted new manner of speaking? (5)
26. Captain's plan: capturing insurgents' leader (5)
29. Mongrels eating skin of amphibian creatures with bizarre traits? (7)
30. Wearing skimpy top and skirt, given that it may lead to a slippery slope? (3,4)
31. Some folks – "tea leaves" – take the property of others (5)

**Away**
2. Soldier perhaps captures revolutionary group retreating in front of a trench (7)
4. Genuine retreat: Brown Mountains (7)
6. Intensely vivid and horrific novel: *It* (7)
7. Brief letter to indicate returning visitor from outer space (7)
8. One Roman goddess decapitated (3)
10. Camp's leader torched no fire wood (7)
11. At last, Dominica protecting nature after Boiling Lake shows loss of fluid (7)
12. Completely surrounding stone setup (7)
13. Nervous, tense and awake at night, scratching heads (7)
14. Get rid of departure to become successful (4,3)
16. Gruesome deaths surrounding electronic communication device (7)
17. "Innocent" ruled here out of control, having no drug left out (7)
26. Letter penned by sharp historian (3)

Comment: +1 An incredible cryptic puzzle as always :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The filled grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]